# Sort RecyclerView by Date

Tags: java, android, collections, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to sort a RecyclerView by Date, but I tried too many things and I don't know what to try now. The problem is in the line  **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** because if I don't put doesn't show me the error but doesn't update the recyclerview too

This is what I have now, and shows me that error.

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{st.stc/sharetaxi.sharetaxicabdriver.PendingTrajectRecyclerView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference'

First of all I put all the trajects in the method **GetAllTrajects()** and inside Collections.sort I parse to date the TextView.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pending_traject_recycler_view);

    listPendingTraject=new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerPendingTraject = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.pendingTrajectRecyclerView);
    recyclerPendingTraject.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

      GetAllTrajects();

    Collections.sort(listPendingTraject, new Comparator<PendingTrajectPOJO>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PendingTrajectPOJO pendingTrajectPOJO, PendingTrajectPOJO t1) {
            String Date = pendingTrajectPOJO.getDate();

            String Date1 = t1.getDate();

            Date date=null,date1=null;

            SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy");
            try {
                date = formatDate.parse(Date);
                date1 = formatDate.parse(Date1);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return date.before(date1) ? 1 : 0;

        }
    });
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Inside method GetAllTrajects when I put all the information I call the method **showPendingTraject()**

```
  private void showPendingTraject() {
    listPendingTraject.add(new PendingTrajectPOJO(nameUsers,coordenatesOriginBundle,Origin,Destination,DataIHora,coordenatesDestiBundle,contadorCordenades));

    Log.d("ID",""+nomUser);
    adapter = new AdapterPendingTraject(listPendingTraject);
    recyclerPendingTraject.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to it would be while storing/entering the data in your PendingTrajectPOJO store date in milliseconds which will be of type long instead of String, and then you can easily compare the long values, and sort it.

Suppose your date is 28/05/2018, then you can get it in milliseconds using the following method:

```
String givenDateString = "28/05/2018"; 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
try {
   Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
   long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
   //store this timeInMilliseconds in your POJO object
   System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
} catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and using timeInMilliseconds sort it, just don't forget to convert timeInMilliseconds into a date while displaying in RecyclerView.

```
 Collections.sort(listPendingTraject, new Comparator<PendingTrajectPOJO>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(PendingTrajectPOJO pendingTrajectPOJO, PendingTrajectPOJO t1) {

        long Date = pendingTrajectPOJO.getDate();
        long Date1 = t1.getDate();

        return Date.compareTo(Date1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey @ParagPawar, thanks for answer me. I updated the post, the problem was because the size of the Recycler was one, I tried to do another thing but shows me a different error

Comment: Can you please specify the exception you are getting?

Comment: And it would be helpful if you can show your complete code for this activity!

Comment: Did it, it's up :)

Comment: Just a null pointer exception, the problem is when I do    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: The problem is you're not initializing your adapter and even you've not set it to the recyclerview

Comment: Have you made any custom adapter of type PendingTrajectPOJO?

Comment: @ParaPawar I initialized and now it' doing the notify but not ordering

Comment: Have you tried my way of using time in milliseconds instead of String?

Comment: Yeah, but how I compare the two variables long in the return?

Comment: Thanks @ParagPawar but I can't compare two long

Answer (score 0):

I think below mentioned line is creating a problem.

`String Date =pendingTrajectPOJO.getDate();`

Rename Date to something else and see if it works

Comment: I just show  the error you were getting.Can you show the detail of GetAllTrajects() . It might be the case some line in that code is causing exception which is not letting showPendingTraject() to execute